# React js Два параметра функции

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, route, параметры

есть проблема с кодом: Для идеальной работы функции надо написать в параметрах `props` и `{company}`, проблема в том, что из-за того параметра который на первом месте, react  не видит второго, точнее он не инициализирует второй параметр, подскажите мне чайнику, как можно это исправить?

**P.S.**
Не хотелось бы лезть в глубь `Route`. `Route`- занимаются отрисовкой страницы.

```js
export default function Mypeople(props, {car}) {
  const { match } = props;
    return car.info.name ? (
    <div>good</div>
  ): (<div>bad</div>);
}

Mypeople.propTypes = {
    car: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ car }) => ({
    car
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Mypeople);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: не очень понял вопрос... Видит props, но не видит car?

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин Абсолютно верно

Comment: car и match находятся в props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допедрил сделать вот так вот:

```js
export default function Mypeople(props) {
  const { match } = props;
  const { car } = props;
    return car.info.name ? (
    <div>good</div>
  ): (<div>bad</div>);
}

Mypeople.propTypes = {
    car: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ car }) => ({
    car
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Mypeople);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Всем большое спасибо за ответы!!!!

Comment: Можно объединить в одно: const { match, car } = props;

Answer (score 1):

Если car и match находятся в props, то вам нужно сделать следующим образом:

```
export default function Mypeople(props: {car, match}) {
```

Тогда вам не понадобится даже строка

```
const { match } = props;
```

Comment: Я сделал всё наоборот, большое вам спасибо, вы направили мою мысль в нужное русло!!!!

Comment: рад что все получилось:)